# New Sprint planning when no history data is available

Tags: sprint

What is the technique to be used when you are starting a new sprint (in a new project) when no history data exists. 
Thanks,
Shiva

Comment: Hi, welcome to PM.SE! This question has been answered already, so marking this as duplicated. If you believe there's specific reasons for your question not to be answered on the above links, then check [Can we have a Sprint Zero with no deliverable code?](https://pm.stackexchange.com/q/10450/430) and [Sprint planning](https://pm.stackexchange.com/q/27528/430). If you still believe your main question isn't answered, leave a comment explaining and we'll happily reopen it. Thanks and welcome again!

Answer (score 1):

Sprint Planning is the meeting in which the team plans the work to be performed in the sprint. For example, [from the Scrum Guide](https://scrumguides.org/scrum-guide.html#events-planning):

> Sprint Planning answers the following:
>
> - What can be delivered in the Increment resulting from the upcoming Sprint?
> - How will the work needed to deliver the Increment be achieved?

Just have a discussion around these two questions. Why do you need history data?

Take the most valuable items from the top of your backlog, discuss them, estimate them, talk about how you can build them, see how much of the work you can fit in the sprint, then go to work.

Create whatever data you need to have something usable at the end of the sprint, something you can inspect and adapt. Nobody expects you to have a full product after the first sprint, so all the data behind the application will also not be there. But you do need to create something useful that you can use to gather feedback, and use that feedback to plan your next sprints.

For extra details, see if this [question from softwareengineering.SE](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/223380/247363) helps.